# Azure Streaming Analytics stateful aggregation

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have an IoT hub with several devices that send data to Streaming analytics. The messages from devices contain information about their health in float (between 0 and 1). The streaming analytics outputs the data to service bus and I want to add information about the field that contains the average health across devices at given moment.

I wanted to use user-defined aggregates to produce this value every 10 seconds, but it looks like it uses only the last message in the timeframe.

Am I using UDA correctly and if not is there any other way to have an average across several devices or some other stateful functions?

UDA code:

```
function main() {
this.init = function () {
    this.state = {};
}

this.accumulate = function (value, device_id) {
    this.state[device_id] = value;
}

/*this.deaccumulate = function (value, timestamp) {
    this.state -= value;
}

this.deaccumulateState = function (otherState) {
      this.state -= otherState.state;
}*/

this.computeResult = function () {
    length = 0,
    total  = 0;
    for (var device in this.state) {
        total += this.state[device];
        length++;
    }
    return total/length;
}
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT
uda.fleetHealth(device_health_status.level, device_id) as avg_health
INTO
    bustopic2
FROM
    iotdata
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the last message as  1 you are using map in Java script. 2 the second parameter are always same and equal to application timestamp even you define it as device_id. 
if you want to calculate the average level for all devices, you should do like this:

```
function UDASample() {
    this.init = function () {
        this.state = 0;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    this.accumulate = function (value, timestamp) {
        this.state += value;
        this.length = length + 1;
    }

    /*this.deaccumulate = function (value, timestamp) {
        this.state -= value;
    }

    this.deaccumulateState = function (otherState) {
          this.state -= otherState.state;
    }*/

    this.computeResult = function () {
        return this.state/this.length;
    }
}

SELECT
uda.fleetHealth(device_health_status.level) as avg_health
INTO
    bustopic2
FROM
    iotdata
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 10)
```

if you want to statistic the average level for each devices, you can use same UDA above and use script like this:

```
SELECT device_id,
uda.fleetHealth(device_health_status.level) as avg_health
INTO
    bustopic2
FROM
    iotdata
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 10), device_id
```